# Dropdown menu like this in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

the client has requested that I make a dropdown menu that works like this in wordpress.

Does anyone know if something like this can be created and styled using the native wordpress menu section?  I'm just not sure about having sub menu items also appear all under one dropdown section.

http://www.playtime.com/

Can someone please steer me in the right direction or offer a bit of guidance? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Please read the FAQ on what is acceptable in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-mega-menu/

This Wordpress plugin may or may not work for you. It hasn't been updated since 2012 but is worth a try, and you can do some very nice effects with it.

Demo site: http://www.designchemical.com/lab/demo-wordpress-jquery-mega-menu-plugin/

To see more menus like the one you described, try searching "mega menu" in Google.

Comment: Thanks, got me on the right track!

Comment: Ended up using this, thanks.